# Laravel 5.5 Override vendor class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to override (not extend) a vendor class. So whenever the vendor class gets called (within the vendor code), I want it to call my custom class.

It looks like I need to alias the class in my `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider`

I've tried this:

```
$loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias('Vendor\VendorName\Class', 'App\Vendor\MyCustomClass');
```

But this doesn't do anything.

I can get my class registered fine:

```
 $this->app->register(
       'App\Vendor\MyCustomClass'
   );
```

But this then fails as the constructor relys on other variables not available at that point. I literally just need the app to override any call to `Vendor\VendorName\Class` with `App\Vendor\MyCustomClass`

Comment: You should to create own service provider extendind the destination class and overwrite it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the solution was create a new ServiceProvider

```
php artisan make:provider MyServiceProvider
```

Which extended the Vendor service provider (found within config/app.php). Within that ServiceProvider, add my alias within the overridden `Register` method

```
 $loader->alias('Vendor\VendorName\Class', 'App\Vendor\MyCustomClass');
```

Comment: the trick is that you need to specify your custom class first, and the class you want to override - as second

Comment: for those who look at it at the future : don't forget to add your custom service provider on Config\App.php on providers array. thanks me later

Comment: this is not working i did every thing, "vendor\beyondcode\laravel-er-diagram-generator\src\GraphBuilder" => "app\Support\vendor\LaravelGraphBuilder"