# How to override vendor method in laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel

I try to override method of vendor class:

```
namespace App\Providers\Rewritten;

use Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue;

class MyDatabaseQueue extends DatabaseQueue
{

    protected function buildDatabaseRecord($queue, $payload, $availableAt, $attempts = 0)
    {
        //my code here
    }
}
```

And i try to register alias in AppServiceProvider like this:

```
$loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

$loader->alias(
            'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue',
            'App\Providers\Rewritten\MyDatabaseQueue'
        );
```

And then i have error myssage:

```
Class 'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue' not found
```

But why? I don't understand.
Can sombody help with that?

Comment: run `composer dumpautoload`, `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Thx, @MianHaseeb this is solve my problem!

Comment: @Buboon please my answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: @MianHaseeb sorry, my folt, this is don't works. Have same eerror not found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.5 Override vendor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925618/laravel-5-5-override-vendor-class)

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to the alias() method are in the wrong order. Instead of:

```
$loader->alias(
    'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue',
    'App\Providers\Rewritten\MyDatabaseQueue'
);
```

You need to switch them:

```
$loader->alias(
    'App\Providers\Rewritten\MyDatabaseQueue',
    'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue'
);
```

The first argument is your class, and the second argument is the alias, which means that the old class name will be an alias to your new class.

Comment: Good catch, if true. I'd suggest providing a link to documentation or API reference where this is stated.

Answer (score -1):

try adding `use Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue;` in AppServiceProvider.php